# Array containing all instances of views with Tag = x

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Is there a way to create an array containing actual instances of views.  For example, if I have one LinearLayout called Container that has within it 3 other LinearLayouts with the same Tag attribute and I wanted to get a list containing all 3 LinearLayouts so I can loop through and handle each.

Tried:

```
LinearLayout[] layouts = (LinearLayout[]) Container.FindViewWithTag(tag);
```

and

```
List<LinearLayout> layouts = (List<LinearLayout>) Container.FindViewWithTag(tag);
```

and

```
foreach(LinearLayout layouts in Container.FindViewWithTag(tag))
```

None of these have been acceptable to Android so far.  Another acceptable way to handle my situation would be to just be able to assign each LinearLayout a Parent.  But I haven't found a way to programatically set a view's parent, only how to get a view's parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have understood from your question that you want the child of Linear Layout. Yes, you can get the child of linear layout by container.getChild(index)

```
for(int i=0;i<container.getChildCount();i++){
       View child=container.getChildAt(i);
       //your processing....
  }
```

Comment: Sorry.  Please allow me to try to clarify.  I have my containing LinearLayout to which I am appending a number of other LinearLayouts.  It is these new layouts for which I am trying to create some sort of Parent/Child relationship between. Hence the shared tags which is my attempt at "grouping" the layouts with a parent. Originally tried to use an ExpandableListView which makes way more sense and would make this a ton easier, but I spent too many hours banging my head against the wall with using clickable views that I abandoned that and just tried creating my own "ExpandableListView".

Comment: Why dont you use default widget of ExpandlableListView ? Are you getting a problem of click in Default control of ExpandlableListView?

Comment: Like I said, I started with ExpandableListView.  But I had CheckBoxes, AutoCompleteTextViews and Buttons in there and was having issue after issue with it.

Comment: I can help you to get rid of those problems which you are facing in Expandable ListView, it is good practice to use default controls.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318920/clickable-views-in-customer-expandablelistview