# Clickable Views in Custom ExpandableListView

Tags: android, xamarin.android

transferAvailPowered.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:focusable="false"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:padding="5dp"
android:gravity="left">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/availSerial"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".30"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="left" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/availModel"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".30"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="left" />
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/availSite"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:hint="To Site"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="left" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/addToTransfer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/addsmall"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:gravity="left" />
```

transferAvailAttached.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:focusable="false"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:padding="5dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/availSerial"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".30"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="right" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/availModel"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".30"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center" />
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/include"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_checkbox" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/removeAttachment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/deletesmall"
    android:gravity="right" />
```

Adapter

```
class EquipAdapter : BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
    private List<CPEquipment> Parent { get; set; }
    private List<List<CPEquipment>> Child { get; set; }
    private Context _context { get; set; }
    private IListAdapter _adapter { get; set; }
    private ExpandableListView _list { get; set; }

    public EquipAdapter(Context context, List<CPEquipment> parent, List<List<CPEquipment>> child, IListAdapter adapter, ExpandableListView list)
    {
        _context = context;
        Parent = parent;
        Child = child;
        _adapter = adapter;
        _list = list;
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        List<CPEquipment> level1 = Child.ElementAt(groupPosition);
        CPEquipment level2 = level1.ElementAt(childPosition);
        E e = new E() {Serial = level2.Serial, Model = level2.Model};
        return e;
    }

    public override long GetChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(groupPosition.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + childPosition.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }

    public override int GetChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {
        return Child.ElementAt(groupPosition).Count;
    }

    public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)_context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.transferAvailAttached, null);
        }

        E e = (E)GetChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        TextView serial = (TextView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.availSerial);
        serial.Text = e.Serial;
        TextView model = (TextView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.availModel);
        model.Text = e.Model;          

        return convertView;
    }

    public override Object GetGroup(int groupPosition)
    {
        CPEquipment c = Parent.ElementAt(groupPosition);
        E e = new E(){Serial = c.Serial, Model = c.Model, Type = c.Status}; 

        return e;
    }

    public override long GetGroupId(int groupPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public override View GetGroupView(int groupPosition, bool isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        E e = (E)GetGroup(groupPosition);

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)_context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
                convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.transferAvailPowered, null);
     }

        TextView serial = (TextView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.availSerial);
        serial.Text = e.Serial;
        TextView model = (TextView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.availModel);
        model.Text = e.Model;
        AutoCompleteTextView acText = (AutoCompleteTextView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.availSite);
        acText.Adapter = _adapter;

        _list.ExpandGroup(groupPosition);

        return convertView;
    }

    public override bool IsChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override int GroupCount
    {
        get { return Parent.Count; }
    }

    public override bool HasStableIds
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

}
```

Outcome:

[image]

In this scenario, the AutoCompleteTextView in the parent group and the green plus button should be "selectable" so that the user can input the info into the field and click that button without collapsing the group.  And the CheckBox and the red x button in the child should also be "selectable" so the user can check the CheckBox and click the button.  The only part of that that actually works is that the CheckBox is selectable and the group doesn't collapse because for lack of a better term, the group layout is "dead" and does nothing when pressed.  And the seemingly "working" CheckBox isn't even so because it does this weird thing where checking or unchecking one will randomly check or uncheck others.

Comment: In your code there is snippet of Button or checkBox code ?

Comment: Yes.  Please look at the xml included.  There is an ImageButton in the first one and both a CheckBox and ImageButton in the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is to resolve checkbox problem "CheckBox isn't even so because it does this weird thing where checking or unchecking one will randomly check or uncheck others." Along with ImageButton and CheckBox handling.

```
public override View GetChildView(final int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)_context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
    convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.transferAvailAttached, null);

    E e = (E)GetChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    TextView serial = (TextView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.availSerial);
    serial.Text = e.Serial;
    TextView model = (TextView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.availModel);
    model.Text = e.Model;     

    CheckBox include = (CheckBox)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.include); 

    include.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //DO your checkbox handling here
        }
    });

    ImageButton removeAttachment =(CheckBox)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id. removeAttachment);  

    removeAttachment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //DO your imageButton handling here
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

public override View GetGroupView(final int groupPosition, bool isExpanded, View convertview, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View convertView = convertview;
    if (convertView == null) 
    {
        E e = (E)GetGroup(groupPosition);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)_context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        convertView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.transferAvailPowered, null);
    }

    TextView serial = (TextView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.availSerial);
    serial.Text = e.Serial;
    TextView model = (TextView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.availModel);
    model.Text = e.Model;
    AutoCompleteTextView acText = (AutoCompleteTextView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.availSite);
    acText.Adapter = _adapter;

    ImageButton addToTransfer =(CheckBox)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id. addToTransfer);  

    addToTransfer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                        
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //DO your addToTransfer imageButton handling here

        }
    });

    _list.ExpandGroup(groupPosition);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: So good news and bad news.  Good news is, it appears the CheckBoxes and AutoCompleteTextViews are no longer mirroring one another.  Bad news is now as soon as you scroll or after the AutoCompleteTextView loses focus or anything the values reset to their defaults.  Is there some kind of event in the ExpandableListView I need to be catching and handling or is it in the Views themselves?

Comment: Yes you have to manually handle that by storing data persistently or you have to maintain the Array of textView text .

Comment: Instead of setting the OnClickListener you could also just subscribe to the Click events of the `removeAttachment` and `addToTransfer` ImageButtons. Also similarly the Checkboxes have similar events. This makes it easier to access things that is happening in GetChildView and GetGroupView directly.

Comment: Thanks.  This seems like way more of a pain than just appending some LinearLayouts to a ScrollView. I know that it is not the recommended way, but it is working like a charm.  Thanks anyway.